Trying to install flutter by first following instructions to install cocopods on Mac Studio with macOS Sonoma version 14.5
Trying to install flutter by first following instructions to install cocoapods on Mac Studio with macOS Sonoma version 14.5 and there was an error:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of securerandom (>= 0.3) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.3.2. Try installing it with `gem install securerandom -v 0.3.2` and then running the current command again
    securerandom requires Ruby version >= 3.1.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

tried this command
% brew install ruby
zsh: command not found: brew

So what's the command for securerandom requires Ruby version >= 3.1.0.
tried this command
% brew install ruby
zsh: command not found: brew

So what's the command for securerandom requires Ruby version >= 3.1.0.
